# Custom php file for a specific child site of Wordpress MU

Tags: wordpress

i want to have a custom php file on one of my child sites of Wordpress multisite network.

For example: child3.mydomain.com/somecustomfile.php

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are looking for, but this is how I used to solve this problem:

In the specific child site, create page with your any name (but remember the page slug!). In the theme, create a file named [page-slug.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) (replace slug with the slug of the page you just created). The file is now accessible under the URL of the page you just created.